# Dynamic className manipulation in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am havving a problem with dynamic class change in my react component. In a simple slider i want to display only selected image.
My component looks like this:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import './Slider.scss';

import SliderImage from './SliderImage';

import photo1 from '../../../Images/photo1.jpg';
import photo2 from '../../../Images/photo2.jpg';
import photo3 from '../../../Images/photo3.jpg';
import photo4 from '../../../Images/photo4.jpg';
import photo5 from '../../../Images/photo5.jpg';

function Slider() {
  let slideArr = [
    {
      id: 1,
      src: photo1,
      text: 'Far far away, behind the word mountains',
      alt: 'wedding_photo',
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      src: photo2,
      text: 'Far far away, behind the word mountains',
      alt: 'wedding_photo',
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      src: photo3,
      text: 'Far far away, behind the word mountains',
      alt: 'wedding_photo',
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      src: photo4,
      text: 'Far far away, behind the word mountains',
      alt: 'wedding_photo',
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      src: photo5,
      text: 'Far far away, behind the word mountains',
      alt: 'wedding_photo',
    },
  ];
  const [x, setX] = useState(0);
  const goLeft = () => {
    console.log(x);
    x === 0 ? setX(-100 * (slideArr.length - 1)) : setX(x + 100);
  };
  const goRight = () => {
    console.log(x);
    x === -100 * (slideArr.length - 1) ? setX(0) : setX(x - 100);
  };

  return (
    <div className='Slider'>
      {slideArr.map((item) => {
        return (
          <div
            className={`Slider__Slide + ${item.id - 1 === x ? 'active' : ''}`}
            key={item.id}
            style={{ transform: `translateX(${x}%)` }}>
            <SliderImage
              classTxt={'Slider__Slide-txt'}
              classImg={'Slider__Slide-img'}
              src={item.src}
              text={item.text}
              alt={item.alt}
            />
          </div>
        );
      })}

      <button id='goLeft' onClick={goLeft}>
        left
      </button>
      <button id='goRight' onClick={goRight}>
        right
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Slider;
```

So i have array with photos, that have ids. Based on Id I am showing an image in SliderImage component. This part works good. Images are changing, but I am unable to dynamicly change classNames

Here i want to change class
`` className={`Slider__Slide + ${item.id - 1 === x ? 'active' : ''}`} ``
but onClick is not adding `active` to new image.

Thanks for any help

Comment: I decided to drop hooks and just do a class component. It took me like 15 min to get this working as i want. Thanks all for help

Answer (score 2):

You are using string literals in a way as if you were concatenating two strings. Everything inside the back ticks will be as it is if they are not variables.

```
  className={`Slider__Slide + ${item.id - 1 === x ? 'active' : ''}`}
```

Here you are using the plus sign and it will be `classname + active` when it is evaluated what you want to do is basically remove the plus sign.

```
  className={`Slider__Slide ${item.id - 1 === x ? 'active' : ''}`}
```

I would suggest you to use the [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) library for such use cases when you have to do a conditional chaining for classes. The following example demonstrates how it would be let's say our item object looks like the following and x is defined in a way that it would evaluate to true.

```js
const item = {
  id: 3
};

const x = 2;

const classes = classNames({ firstClassName: true, bar: item.id - 1 === x });

console.log(classes)  // => 'className active'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is fundamentally a string concatenation question. The JSX expression you have has spaces and a `+` **as text** inside a template literal. Either use `+` with string literals or use a template literal, but not both.

Using string literals:

```
className={"Slider__Slide " + (item.id - 1 === x ? "active" : "")}
```

Using a template literal:

```
className={`Slider__Slide ${item.id - 1 === x ? "active" : ""}`}
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks, but this also is not working. Template literal is not adding anything. Only first photo is having class active

Comment: @shivetay - Then `item.id - 1` is not `=== x`. Looking at your code, you're changing `x` in a way that seems like it'll be **very** far away from the `id` values you've shown (adding/subtracting `100`). You need to ensure that `x` is only the values `0` through `4` (with the code you've shown). The above **will** correctly output `active` when `x` has matching value.

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest two things

1. Change the meaning of 'x' to be the current id instead of the position
2. Replace the "+" from string template, since it's resulting into a literal "+"  `Slider__Slide + ${item.id - 1 === x ? 'active' : ''}` => "Slider__Slide + active" or "Slider__Slide + "

   ```
      const [x, setX] = useState(0);

      const goLeft = () => {
        console.log(x);
        x === 0 ? setX(slideArr.length - 1) : setX(x);
      };

       const goRight = () => {
         console.log(x);
         x === (slideArr.length - 1) ? setX(0) : setX(x);
       };
   ```

on return

```
      <div
        className={`Slider__Slide${item.id - 1 === x ? 'active' : ''}`}
        key={item.id}
        style={{ transform: `translateX(${x * (-100}%)` }}>
        <SliderImage
          classTxt={'Slider__Slide-txt'}
          classImg={'Slider__Slide-img'}
          src={item.src}
          text={item.text}
          alt={item.alt}
        />
      </div>
```